# Google place API key

Tags: java, android

So my question is.. I have created a map activity & I am using the google place API key for requests to find locations on the map.
I have took the basic structure of the search function & I am trying to use it in order to get results.. but I have 2 problems with this.
1. My API key is limited to 1 search per day.. cant understand why.
2. when I am running a search with it I always get zero results.. also don't know why.
Can some one please help me with this issue ?
Thx.
Nimrod

Below, is my search line :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input="+Uri.encode(query)+"&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name&key="+apiKey

Answer (score 0):

New pricing changes went into effect on July 16, 2018. For more information, check out the Guide for Existing Users.

Please check for more info:https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing